# Mat paginator length issue and next previous is not working

Tags: angular

how can i set the length for mat paginator,
Issue im facing is next previous is not enabled in mat paginator,

[image]
When i console, mat paginator lenght is 0, how can i resolve it??

[image]

Comment: Can you show your html code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-paginator [length]="100"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
              aria-label="Select page">
</mat-paginator>
```

More information is here https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview